# Splunk: comparison of current day events from 8 am to 6 pm with the previous day from 8 am to 6 pm, grouping into several days

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm trying to compare the events of the current day from 8am to 6pm with the previous day from 8am to 6pm, and display the results in a table according to the journey, I'm using multi search but it's not working correctly, can you help me help with tips?

```
| multisearch  
[
search

index=raw_iis   
| search 
(
 (ACOMPANHAMENTO*)
)
| timechart  span=1d
count(eval(time_taken >0)) as TotalRequisições
count(eval(time_taken <6000 AND (sc_status=="200" OR sc_status=="201" OR sc_status=="204"))) as QtdRequisicoesMenor6seg 
eval(avg(time_taken)) as TempoMedioResp
| eval "% abaixo de 6s" =  (QtdRequisicoesMenor6seg/TotalRequisições)*100
| appendcols 
  [ search index=raw_iis 
    (earliest=-2d@d+8h latest=-2d@d+18h)  
  | search  
  (
    ACOMPANHAMENTO*
  ) 
  | timechart span=1d 
    count(eval(time_taken >0)) as DiaAntTotalRequisições
    count(eval(time_taken <6000 AND (sc_status=="200" OR sc_status=="201" OR sc_status=="204"))) as DiaAntQtdRequisicoesMenor6seg 
    eval(avg(time_taken)) as DiaAntTempoMedioResp
  | eval "Dia Ant % abaixo de 6s" =  (DiaAntQtdRequisicoesMenor6seg/DiaAntTotalRequisições)*100
  | head 1 ]
| eval "Diferença do dia Anterior" =  ('% abaixo de 6s') - ('Dia Ant % abaixo de 6s')
| eval Jornada = "Acompanhamento"]
| table Jornada, _time, TotalRequisições, QtdRequisicoesMenor6seg, TempoMedioResp, "% abaixo de 6s", "Diferença do dia Anterior"

[search 
index=raw_iis   
| search 
( 
  (MelhorConversa*) 
)
| timechart  span=1d
count(eval(time_taken >0)) as TotalRequisições
count(eval(time_taken <6000 AND (sc_status=="200" OR sc_status=="201" OR sc_status=="204"))) as QtdRequisicoesMenor6seg 
eval(avg(time_taken)) as TempoMedioResp
| eval "% abaixo de 6s" =  (QtdRequisicoesMenor6seg/TotalRequisições)*100
| appendcols 
  [ search index=raw_iis 
    (earliest=-2d@d+8h latest=-2d@d+18h)  
  | search  (MelhorConversa*) 
  | timechart span=1d 
    count(eval(time_taken >0)) as DiaAntTotalRequisições
    count(eval(time_taken <6000 AND (sc_status=="200" OR sc_status=="201" OR sc_status=="204"))) as DiaAntQtdRequisicoesMenor6seg 
  eval(avg(time_taken)) as DiaAntTempoMedioResp
  | eval "Dia Ant % abaixo de 6s" =  (DiaAntQtdRequisicoesMenor6seg/DiaAntTotalRequisições)*100
  | head 1 ]
| eval "Diferença do dia Anterior" =  ('% abaixo de 6s') - ('Dia Ant % abaixo de 6s')
| eval Jornada = "MelhorConversa"]
| table Jornada, _time, TotalRequisições, QtdRequisicoesMenor6seg, TempoMedioResp, "% abaixo de 6s", "Diferença do dia Anterior" 

[search 
index=raw_iis   
| search 
( 
  (Reagendamento*) 
)
| timechart  span=1d
count(eval(time_taken >0)) as TotalRequisições
count(eval(time_taken <6000 AND (sc_status=="200" OR sc_status=="201" OR sc_status=="204"))) as QtdRequisicoesMenor6seg 
eval(avg(time_taken)) as TempoMedioResp
| eval "% abaixo de 6s" =  (QtdRequisicoesMenor6seg/TotalRequisições)*100
| appendcols 
  [ search index=raw_iis 
    (earliest=-2d@d+8h latest=-2d@d+18h)  
  | search  (Reagendamento*) 
  | timechart span=1d 
    count(eval(time_taken >0)) as DiaAntTotalRequisições
    count(eval(time_taken <6000 AND (sc_status=="200" OR sc_status=="201" OR sc_status=="204"))) as DiaAntQtdRequisicoesMenor6seg 
  eval(avg(time_taken)) as DiaAntTempoMedioResp
  | eval "Dia Ant % abaixo de 6s" =  (DiaAntQtdRequisicoesMenor6seg/DiaAntTotalRequisições)*100
  | head 1 ]
| eval "Diferença do dia Anterior" =  ('% abaixo de 6s') - ('Dia Ant % abaixo de 6s')
| eval Jornada = "Reagendamento"]
| table Jornada, _time, TotalRequisições, QtdRequisicoesMenor6seg, TempoMedioResp, "% abaixo de 6s", "Diferença do dia Anterior"
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "it's not working correctly".  What exactly do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: does not work, it gives the error:
Error in 'multisearch' command: At least two searches must be specified.

I expected it to return several rows from the table according to the journey

Comment: you cannot use transforming commands (eg `timechart`) in a `multisearch` - all transforming commands must occur on the issuing Search Head *after* all the independent searches of the `multisearch` have completed

Answer (score 1):

The `multisearch` command requires at least two subsearches (otherwise, it's not *multi*search).  A subsearch is a sequence of SPL commands within square brackets `[]`.

Your query has three instances of `[search`, which implies three subsearches, but none of them are closed by a `]` so Splunk considers them a single search.

UPDATE:
You probably don't need `multisearch`.  Use `append`, instead.  The effect is the same without the limitations.

BTW, a solution that uses `appendcols` usually is the wrong solution.  It requires the subsearch to return the same number of results in the exact same order as the main search, which is rarely the case.  Use `append`, instead.

```
index=raw_iis "ACOMPANHAMENTO*"
| timechart  span=1d
count(eval(time_taken >0)) as TotalRequisições
count(eval(time_taken <6000 AND (sc_status=="200" OR sc_status=="201" OR sc_status=="204"))) as QtdRequisicoesMenor6seg 
eval(avg(time_taken)) as TempoMedioResp
| eval "% abaixo de 6s" =  (QtdRequisicoesMenor6seg/TotalRequisições)*100
| appendcols 
  [ search index=raw_iis 
    (earliest=-2d@d+8h latest=-2d@d+18h) "ACOMPANHAMENTO*" 
  | timechart span=1d 
    count(eval(time_taken >0)) as DiaAntTotalRequisições
    count(eval(time_taken <6000 AND (sc_status=="200" OR sc_status=="201" OR sc_status=="204"))) as DiaAntQtdRequisicoesMenor6seg 
    eval(avg(time_taken)) as DiaAntTempoMedioResp
  | eval "Dia Ant % abaixo de 6s" =  (DiaAntQtdRequisicoesMenor6seg/DiaAntTotalRequisições)*100
  | head 1 ]
| eval "Diferença do dia Anterior" =  ('% abaixo de 6s') - ('Dia Ant % abaixo de 6s')
| eval Jornada = "Acompanhamento"]
| table Jornada, _time, TotalRequisições, QtdRequisicoesMenor6seg, TempoMedioResp, "% abaixo de 6s", "Diferença do dia Anterior"

| append [search index=raw_iis "MelhorConversa*"
  | timechart  span=1d
    count(eval(time_taken >0)) as TotalRequisições
    count(eval(time_taken <6000 AND (sc_status=="200" OR sc_status=="201" OR sc_status=="204"))) as QtdRequisicoesMenor6seg 
eval(avg(time_taken)) as TempoMedioResp
  | eval "% abaixo de 6s" =  (QtdRequisicoesMenor6seg/TotalRequisições)*100
  | appendcols 
    [ search index=raw_iis (earliest=-2d@d+8h latest=-2d@d+18h)  "MelhorConversa*)"
    | timechart span=1d 
      count(eval(time_taken >0)) as DiaAntTotalRequisições
      count(eval(time_taken <6000 AND (sc_status=="200" OR sc_status=="201" OR sc_status=="204"))) as DiaAntQtdRequisicoesMenor6seg 
    eval(avg(time_taken)) as DiaAntTempoMedioResp
    | eval "Dia Ant % abaixo de 6s" =  (DiaAntQtdRequisicoesMenor6seg/DiaAntTotalRequisições)*100
    | head 1 ]
  | eval "Diferença do dia Anterior" =  ('% abaixo de 6s') - ('Dia Ant % abaixo de 6s')
  | eval Jornada = "MelhorConversa"]
| append [search index=raw_iis "Reagendamento*"
  | timechart  span=1d
    count(eval(time_taken >0)) as TotalRequisições
    count(eval(time_taken <6000 AND (sc_status=="200" OR sc_status=="201" OR sc_status=="204"))) as QtdRequisicoesMenor6seg 
  eval(avg(time_taken)) as TempoMedioResp
  | eval "% abaixo de 6s" =  (QtdRequisicoesMenor6seg/TotalRequisições)*100
  | appendcols 
    [ search index=raw_iis (earliest=-2d@d+8h latest=-2d@d+18h)  "Reagendamento*"
    | timechart span=1d 
      count(eval(time_taken >0)) as DiaAntTotalRequisições
      count(eval(time_taken <6000 AND (sc_status=="200" OR sc_status=="201" OR sc_status=="204"))) as DiaAntQtdRequisicoesMenor6seg 
    eval(avg(time_taken)) as DiaAntTempoMedioResp
    | eval "Dia Ant % abaixo de 6s" =  (DiaAntQtdRequisicoesMenor6seg/DiaAntTotalRequisições)*100
    | head 1 ]
  | eval "Diferença do dia Anterior" =  ('% abaixo de 6s') - ('Dia Ant % abaixo de 6s')
  | eval Jornada = "Reagendamento"]
| table Jornada, _time, TotalRequisições, QtdRequisicoesMenor6seg, TempoMedioResp, "% abaixo de 6s", "Diferença do dia Anterior"
```

Comment: I include the closing, maybe it's not in the right place, can you help me and indicate where it should be in my query?

I closed on the lines below


| eval Jornada = "Acompanhamento"]

| eval Jornada = "MelhorConversa"]

Comment: That's better, but you still have a single subsearch in the `multisearch`.  The intervening `| table` commands break the `multisearch`.  I think you only need one `table` command at the end.

Comment: even leaving only one table at the end, it presents an error:

Error in 'multisearch' command: Multisearch subsearches might only contain purely streaming operations (subsearch 1 contains a non-streaming command).

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere!  Unfortunately, the fix is not a simple.  You need to change the subsearches to remove the non-streaming commands.  I'll update my answer.